# How to set cursor focus onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsf, focus

I use h:selectOneRadio tag.
I need to set the cursor focus to first radio field.

```
<f:view>
<html>
     <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">      
     </head>
     <body>
         <h:form id="focusForm" >
              <h:selectOneRadio id="testRadioId" value="">
                     <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="JSF" />
                     <f:selectItem id="si2" itemLabel="JSP" />
              </h:selectOneRadio>
         </h:form>
</body></html></f:view>
```

here The Firefox (browser) assign id :**focusForm:testRadioId:0** that field.
So i use the following script:

```
document.getElementById("focusForm:testRadioId:0").focus();
```

But,
Some times, i may change dynamically disable the radio field from backing bean.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="testRadioId" value="">
                 <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="JSF" itemDisabled="true"/>
                 <f:selectItem id="si2" itemLabel="JSP" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

So here i disable the first radio button.
Now, If i use the same script, then not set cursor focus to first radio field.
how to handle this? that means how to alter my script dynamically during onload?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**:

Thanks BaluC.

The following code is worked.

```
 <a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">   
         function setFocusRadioField()
         {
              jQuery(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus(); 
          }
 </script>

<body onload="setFocusRadioField();">
</body>
```

But the ***following code is not worked.***
I test the following way:

```
jQuery('#focusForm\:testRadioId:enabled:first').focus();
```

Then,

```
jQuery('#focusForm\\:testRadioId:enabled:first').focus();
```

Then,

```
var id = "#focusForm:testRadioId:enabled:first".replace(/:/g, "\\:");
jQuery(id).focus();
```

I don't know where i make the error.
Better, I need set the cursor focus using id. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, here's a jQuery solution:

```
$('[id^=focusForm:testRadioId]:enabled:first').focus();
```

The `[id^=name]` selector will return all elements starting with name `name`.

If your intent is actually to focus the first non-hidden and non-disabled input element of the page, regardless of the input type, then use this:

```
$(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for your full support. Now i check it the first code. [id^=name]. Its perfectly worked.

Comment: $('[id^=focusForm:testRadioId]:enabled:first').focus();
Its worked in FIreFox. Not worked in IE6,IE8.
I have no other browser. Still i am not check any other browser.

Comment: ya.i check it. Its worked in IE's. But one problem in IE:
After page loading, i can't see the cursor focus in radio field.But, if i press TAB button (first time after page load), then move the cursor focus to the next component.

Comment: For example , 
i have TEXTFIELD-1, radio-Field, TEXTFIELD-2 . 
I wrote code for focus the radio field during onload .  
In IE8, After loading , i can't see the cursor focus to radio field. But after loading i press tab key, then move the cursor focus to TEXTFIELD-2.
This problem onle IE. Not FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to use javascript for this. Place js function call in the body tag of the HTML. Define the javascript function in your js file, or at least before calling it from the body tag. So if you're going to define the function in the HTML file, do it early.

HTML:

```
<body onload=formFocus()>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function formFocus()
    {
        focusForm.si1.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: From the question: *"But,
Some times, i may change dynamically disable the radio field from backing bean"*. This answer doesn't cover that.